# There's a alternative for ResponseEntity in Quarkus?

Tags: java, rest, quarkus

there's a way to code a ResponseEntity like this `return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("The input vote is not valid")`, in quarkus?
I'm seaching for something like this, but I only found the RestResponse and didn't  have the implementation that I need.

I've tried `

```
RestResponse.notFound()
```

But is not like the Spring ResponseEntity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using RESTEasy, then use a [`ResponseBuilder`](https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#returning-a-response-body).

Code from docs

> ```
> package org.acme.rest;
>
> import java.time.Duration; 
> import java.time.Instant; 
> import java.util.Date;
>
> import javax.ws.rs.GET; 
> import javax.ws.rs.Path; 
> import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType; 
> import javax.ws.rs.core.NewCookie;
>
> import org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.RestResponse; 
> import org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.RestResponse.ResponseBuilder;
>
> @Path("") 
> public class Endpoint {
>
>     @GET
>     public RestResponse<String> hello() {
>         // HTTP OK status with text/plain content type
>         return ResponseBuilder.ok("Hello, World!", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
>          // set a response header
>          .header("X-Cheese", "Camembert")
>          // set the Expires response header to two days from now
>          .expires(Date.from(Instant.now().plus(Duration.ofDays(2))))
>          // send a new cookie
>          .cookie(new NewCookie("Flavour", "chocolate"))
>          // end of builder API
>          .build();
>     } 
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks!! I use RestResponse.ResponseBuilder.create(RestResponse.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build().